# C# backup of datatier database works fine in debug environment, but exceptions occur after release

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, dac

I now have the following code to backup the database

```cs
public class SqlServerBacpac
{
    public static void Startup(ServerConfigOption option)
    {
        var connectionString = SqlClientHelper.BuildSqlConnectionString(option);
        var fileName = option.Database + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString(option.Format) + ".bacpac";
        var filePath = Path.Combine(option.Folder, fileName);
        var ds = new DacServices(connectionString);
        ds.ExportBacpac(filePath, option.Database);
    }
}
```

use nuget package

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac
```

In debug environment, everything works fine

Posting a configuration file

[image: configuration]

However, the following problem occurred after the release

```
Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentException: The path is empty. (Parameter 'path')
   at System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(String path)
   at System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(String fileName)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Dac.DacOrigin.Operation.SetOperatingAssembly(Assembly assembly)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Dac.DacOrigin.Operation..ctor(Assembly executingAssembly)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Dac.DacOrigin..ctor(Assembly executingAssembly)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices.<>c__DisplayClass77_1.<CreateExportOperation>b__1()
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Dac.OperationLogger.Capture(Action action)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices.<>c__DisplayClass77_0.<CreateExportOperation>b__0(Object operation, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Operation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext context)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.OperationExtension.CompositeOperation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext context)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.OperationExtension.Execute(IOperation operation, DacLoggingContext loggingContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices.ExportBacpac(Func`1 streamGetter, String databaseName, DacExportOptions exportOptions, IEnumerable`1 tables, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices.ExportBacpac(String packageFileName, String databaseName, DacExportOptions options, IEnumerable`1 tables, Nullable`1 cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices.ExportBacpac(String packageFileName, String databaseName, DacSchemaModelStorageType modelStorageType, IEnumerable`1 tables, Nullable`1 cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices.ExportBacpac(String packageFileName, String databaseName, IEnumerable`1 tables, Nullable`1 cancellationToken)
   at SqlServerBackup.SqlServerBacpac.Startup(ServerConfigOption option)
   at Program.<<Main>$>g__RunOptions|0_1(ServerConfigOption opts)
   at CommandLine.ParserResultExtensions.WithParsed[T](ParserResult`1 result, Action`1 action)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args)
```

I want the release to be usable in any environment, not just an error

Comment: Although the error was reported, the files were backed up as usual. The backed up files are not currently in use, so there is no way to ensure whether the backup was successful.

Comment: According to the error message, please check the path. Please add the breakpoint at this line `var filePath = Path.Combine(option.Folder, fileName);`.  We need to check the value of filePath.